# Firestore batch operation permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Google Firestore provides the ability to perform many operations atomically, as show [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). I'm struggling to find information on when the permissions check for each operation is performed. Here's how a typical call to a `batch` function would look, for example, in Kotlin:

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
val batch = db.batch()

db.collection("cities")
    .whereEqualTo("haveVisited", true)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { cities -> 
        for (city in cities) {
            batch.delete(db.collection("cities").document(city.id))  
        }

        batch.commit()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                // Our delete worked
            }
    }
```

Above is a simple example where we queue all of the delete operations and perform them at once. In this instance I believe that where the permissions check against the Firestore ruleset is performed, either during the `batch.delete()` or the `batch.commit()` is fairly inconsequential.

However, let's consider an example where we're trying to delete multiple documents, some of whom rely on other during the permissions check to determine permissions. Say you have the above cities collection, and then you also have a collection of towns that each reference a city. Multiple towns can reference the same city.

- You want to delete the city; so you should also delete all of the towns that reference the city
- Only a mayor (admin) of the city can delete the towns and city; so the permissions check to delete each town has to check the cities collection to see if the user is the mayor

But then, all of the deletions happen at once. So in this instance, the permissions check would *have* to be performed before any of the operations take place. Furthermore, the user would have to have permissions for every operation, otherwise all will fail.

I assume that this is the case, however I can't find any resources to completely back up my conclusion. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify your point, [there is no operation that atomically deletes a collection](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/delete-collections). Deleting a document does not delete the documents in its subcollections (meaning towns are not wiped out, if the city associated to those towns was deleted).

Security rules would apply only at the matched path, so the access controls defined on the  cities collection do not apply to the towns subcollection. Instead, it would be necessary to write explicit rules to control access to subcollections, as described through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data).

I would like to also point out that in certain cases, it would be useful to break down read and write into more granular operations. For instance, you would like to enforce different conditions on document creation than on document deletion. A read rule can be broken into get and list, while a write rule can be broken into create, update, and delete as shown in this [code snippet](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

Additionally, I would like to direct you to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-structure) as it better outlines the structure of Cloud Firestore Security Rules that allow you to control access to documents and collections in your database.